# How to get invited user information on facebook invite API

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have created a website there have added "Invite from Facebook API". It works fine.

What I want is how to retrieve the invited user data?

My code is-

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<div id="fb-root">
   <p>Invite On Facebook</p>
   <p><input type="button" onclick="invitefriends()" value="Facebook" /></p>
</div>   

function invitefriends(){     
    FB.init({appId: 'xxxxx', xfbml: true, cookie: true});
    FB.ui({
       method: 'send',
       name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
       link:'http://mydomain/UI/home.php'
    });
}
```

which is refer from this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog)

Can any one please help me one this.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog)- "There is no response data from Send Dialog." That means you cannot get the details of the user(s) to whom the message is sent.

I'm not sure what exactly are you trying to do with Send Dialog, but there are other [Dialogs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.ui) too that you can have a look; some have the callback that gives you the id of the friends to whom the request is sent. But of-course it should match with your requirement.

Comment: thanks for reply. my requirement is i need to invite my facebook friends with sending my blog page.and that page is only visible to my invited friends. so is there any way to achieve this? can you please guide me on this.

Comment: I'm still not clear with your req, but I would recommend you to go through the dialogs link I've mentioned and see yourself which suits your requirement.

Comment: from above link "send dialog" is my need where i can share my url to each of my friends but here we cant get the response data. so is there any other facebook API where i can achieve this with getting my invited friends data? thanks